# Annoying the entire world

Tags: probability, statistics, recreational-mathematics

Okay, so I had this conversation with a friend:

> [7時41分48秒] Me: INTERESTING CALCULATION TIME (y)`
>
> [7時41分55秒] Me: if everybody who is annoyed
>
> [7時42分01秒] Friend: lol
>
> [7時42分01秒] Me: will annoy everybody he/she talks to
>
> [7時42分20秒] Me: and each person talks to 4 people a day with a standard deviation (i.e. uncertainty) of 3 people
>
> [7時42分28秒] Me: how long (with 95% confidence interval) will it take for the world to be completely annoyed?

It seems easy to just use the mean and solve a logistic curve. But the normally-distributed random variable seems to mess things up. Normal RV constantly multiplied by itself isn't even symmetrical.

How can I attack this problem?

Comment: If you have a minus two sigma day, how many people do you talk to?  More seriously, giving only mean and sigma seems to imply a normal distribution, but the distribution of people talked to is discrete and always non-negative.  You need to specify the distribution better.

Comment: How bout a binomial distribution with $n=10$ and $p=0.4$?